# z-index in inner div higer than parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible for the z-index of an inner div to be of a higher value and stack above its parent div.

For instance

css

```
#parentdiv{
    z-index: 10;
}

#childiv{
    z-index:12;
}
```

I need this to work because the inner div by default it hidden when it is set to display I want it to be above another `div` (seconddiv) with `z-index:11;` however, the parent `div` must be below seconddiv. I'm sure I can do this using jquery but I was wondering if this could work using css only

Comment: use `z-index:-1` to parent div.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be yes.  That is exactly what z-index is for.  Think of z-index kind of like layers in Photoshop.  In your example above, #childiv would be sitting on top of #parentdiv.  You can also go into negative z-index as well.  As mentioned above you do need to set position.

```
#parentdiv {
position:relative;
z-index:10;
}

#childiv {
position:absolute;
z-index:12;
}
```

Added a Fiddle to help you out.  http://jsfiddle.net/9UMc9/

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. there are three divs; parentdiv childdiv and second div . By default child div is set to hidden. I want parent div to be underneath second div but child div to display above secondiv. I have set the zindex to 10,11,12 for parent, second and child but it doesn't work

Comment: I guess I have to rely on javascript

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9UMc9/2/  I updated the fiddle to display what you are asking for.  In this example.. parent div is black in the background (under second div and child div).  Second div sits on top of parent div.  child div sits on top of second div.  If you add display:none; to second div it will not display but you will still see second div.

Comment: The problem is second div is not nested in parent div like it is in you fiddle

Comment: I think where you are getting hung up is the "position" attribute.  Nesting is mostly irrelevant when you use position.  Divs do not need to be nested when positioned absolutely.  Think of it like a whiteboard and post-it notes.  in this case, #parentdiv is set to position:relative; and the subsequent divs (second and child) are set to absolute.  Think of the parent div (position:relative) like a white board.. and the subsequent divs (child and second) set to position:absolute as post-it notes to put up on the board.  You control the placement by using Top, Left, and z-index of each post-it.

Comment: But all of that being said if you keep them nested and set the parent to display:none then.. no it wont work.  But there is no reason to nest them if you use position.  Simply un-nest them and use position to achieve the affect you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in which I was trying to put a second div "in between" a parent and a child. Unfortunately this is not possible with pure CSS.